# How do I resolve this circular reference in AWS CloudFormation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I’m creating a generic stack template using CloudFormation, and I’ve hit a rather annoying circular reference.

Overall Requirements:

1. I want to be able to provision (a lot of other things, but mainly) an ECS Cluster Service that auto-scales using capacity providers, the capacity providers are using auto-scaling groups, and the auto scaling groups are using a launch template.
2. I don’t want static resource names. This causes issues if a resource has to be re-created due to an update and that particular resource has to have a unique name.

Problem:

Without the launch template “knowing the cluster name” (via UserData) the service tasks get stuck in a PROVISIONING state.

So we have the first dependency chain:

Launch Template <- Cluster (Name)

But the Cluster has a dependency chain of:

Cluster <- Capacity Provider <- AutoScalingGroup <- Launch Template

Thus, we have a circular reference: Cluster <-> Launch Template

——

One way I can think of resolving this is to add a suffix to another resource’s name (one that lives outside of this dependency chain, e.g., the target group) as the Cluster’s name; in that way, it is not static but also removes the circular reference.

My question is: is there a better way?

It feels like there should be a resource that the cluster can subscribe to and the ec2 instance can publish to, which would remove the circular dependency as well as the need to assign resource names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing an update from the GitHub issue. The circular dependency has been broken by introducing a new resource: Cluster Capacity Provider Associations.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-clustercapacityproviderassociations.html

To use it in my example, you:

1. Create Cluster (without specifying name)
2. Create Launch Template (using Ref to get cluster name)
3. Create Auto Scaling Group(s)
4. Create Capacity Provider(s)
5. Create Cluster Capacity Provider Associations <- This is new!

The one gotcha is that you have to wait for the new association to be created before you can create a service on the cluster. So be sure that your service "DependsOn" these associations!

---

**EDIT: As a year has passed, I'll pass on a few more gotchas I've learned.**

By using the setup I've laid out, you are required to enable Scale-In protection on the Auto-Scaling Group (ASG) by the Capacity Provider (CP). And when EC2s have Scale-In protection, deleting the ASG will NOT remove Scale-In protection. As a direct result of this:

1. You cannot automatically remove an ASG that has running EC2s from the template.
2. You cannot automatically delete a stack with an ASG that has active EC2s.

In both cases, you must first set the desired capacity to zero, wait for the EC2s to terminate, and then you can proceed.

Furthermore, if your template is auto-generated in a CI/CD pipeline and makes use of an ECS Cluster with multiple ECS Services, with each Service having its own CP, **be warned** - you will not be able *update* a stack in a way that updates the CPA and removes CPs/Services. This is because **CloudFormation performs Updates before Deletions**; in otherwords, CloudFormation will always attempt to update a CPA *before* it attempts to delete a Service. If the Service isn't deleted, that means the CP is still in use; if the CP is still in use, that means the CPA cannot be updated (for removal of a CP)

You must first set the desired capacity for the service you want to delete to zero, wait for the tasks to stop running, manually delete the service from the ECS Web Console, and then perform the stack update.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no such resource** to break the dependency and the cluster name must be pre-defined. This has already been recognized as a problem and its part of open github issue:

- [[ECS] Full support for Capacity Providers in CloudFormation.](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/631)

One of the issues noted is:

> Break circular dependency so that unnamed clusters can be created

At the moment one **work around** [noted](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/631#issuecomment-778257077) is to partially predefine the name, e.g.:

```
ECSCluster:
  Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  Properties:
    ClusterName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-ECSCluster

LaunchConfiguration:
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
  Properties:
    UserData:
      Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash
          echo ECS_CLUSTER=${AWS::StackName}-ECSCluster >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config
```

Alternatively, one could try to solve that by development of some [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that would be in the form of a lambda function. So you could probably create your unnamed cluster with launch template (LT) that has some dummy name for cluster. Then once the cluster is running, you would use the custom resource to create new version of LT with updated cluster name and refresh your auto-scaling group to use the new LT version. But I'm not sure if this would work. Nevertheless, its something that can be considered at least.

Comment: Thank you! I will watch the GitHub issue for a better resolution =)

For now, I went with a suffixed stack name for the cluster name

Comment: @ChrisPhilips No problem. Hopefully the circular dependencies in ECS will get resolved in near future.

Comment: I've updated the accepted answer, as there is now a resource that breaks the circular dependency chain.

Comment: @ChrisPhilips That's good news. Thanks for letting me know.